Getting 'unknown sender' notification when creating google calendar event via service account
Getting 'unknown sender' notification when creating google calendar event via service account
const auth = new GoogleAuth({
  scopes: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events'
  ],
  keyFile: './src/serviceaccount.json',
  clientOptions: {
    subject: 'xxxx@mydomain.com'
  }
});

const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth: auth });

const apiResponse = await calendar.events.insert({
  calendarId: "xxxx@mydomain.com",
  conferenceDataVersion: 1,
  requestBody: {
    start: {
      dateTime: "2024-10-10T08:00:00+09:00",
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: "2024-10-10T08:30:00+09:00",
    },
    attendees: [{ email: "me@gmail.com" }, { email: "xxxx@mydomain.com" }],
    summary: 'Test Event',
    description: 'Test Event created',
    guestsCanInviteOthers: true,
    conferenceData: {
      createRequest: {
        requestId: randomUUID(),
        conferenceSolutionKey: {
          type: 'hangoutsMeet'
        }
      }
    },
    reminders: {
      useDefault: false,
      overrides: [],
    },
    guestsCanModify: true,
    visibility: 'default',
  }
});

I am using the above code to create a calendar event using google calendar api via google service account. sendUpdates parameter is false so that I don't get any notification via google about the event creation. But when I try this only the first time I am getting the below notification from google and i need to suppress/ disable it and i need help to get this resolved.
Screenshot:


The problem you are encountering is an expected behavior when your service account and your consumer account (gmail.com) doesn't have any interaction. You may refer to this documentation: Manage invitations in Calendar Only if the sender is known: Events are automatically added to your calendar if the sender is in your contacts, part of your organization, or someone you previously interacted with.

So in the sense we cannot do anything from api to suppress this alert ?

Yes. You simply need to adjust your gmail.com calendar settings. Most likely, it's set to Only if the sender is known. To have all invitations automatically add to your calendar and eliminate the error you're experiencing, just change that to From everyone. I'll post it as answer for you to follow it.

Updating Calendar settings to resolve Unknown Sender Notification
Just like what I have said in the comment, this is an expected behavior when your service account and your consumer account (gmail.com) doesn't have any interaction. I've replicated the issue where I sent an Event Invitation to my @gmail.com account from my service account.
Here's an image of the said issue:

Just to clarify, these two accounts don't have any interaction at all. And the reason why you are getting that notification is because the current option enabled in the Google Calendar settings of the @gmail.com user is likely set to Only if the sender is known.
To avoid the error you're getting, simply change that to From everyone so that All invitations are automatically added to your calendar After you change the settings, this is what it should look like if you send another calendar event.

To update the calendar settings of your account from Only is the sender is known to From everyone

Go to the calendar.google.com of your gmail.com and find this in settings:



Reference:

Manage invitations in Calendar


If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer

isn't there any other way that we can suppress this from the google service account end or by configuring some additional parameters in the create event api ?
